# How do I close/cancel/dismiss a spinner after I select an item?

Tags: android

When I select an option It opens an activity but when i finish with that activity and I returnt ot the spinner activity, the spinner is still open.

How can I dismiss it right after I select an item?

```
sp.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {
            boolean firstPop =true;
            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,
                    int pos, long arg3) {
                if (!firstPop) {

                    doMyLogic();
                    sp.????
                }
                firstPop = false;

            }
```

**edit** full code

```
public void showDropDownDialogue() {

        String[] s = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.cities);
        final ArrayAdapter<String> adp = new ArrayAdapter<String>(
                MainActivity.this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, s);

        final Spinner sp = new Spinner(MainActivity.this);
        sp.setPadding(5, 5, 5, 5);
        sp.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
        sp.setAdapter(adp);


        sp.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {
            boolean firstPop =true;

            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,
                    int pos, long arg3) {
                if (!firstPop) {
                    editor.putInt("city_id", pos);
                    editor.commit();
                    Intent stationsIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,
                    StationsActivity.class);
                    startActivity(stationsIntent);


                }
                firstPop = false;

            }

            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }
        });
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
        builder.setView(sp);
        builder.create().show();

    }
```

Comment: That's weird, please post more of your code since it should close itself.

Comment: @sam added the full code to question

Comment: Ok, this makes sense now. nandeesh has already posted the best answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its the dialog that needs to be closed and not the spinner. SO declare AlertDialog as a field

and change dialog show like below.

```
builder.setView(sp);
dialog = builder.create();
dialog.show();
```

And in onItemSelected add

```
dialog.dismiss();
```

Answer (score 1):

you want to implement OnItemSelectedListener and override onItemSelected method get the selected event for spinner, it will close, you don't need to dismiss programmatically

You dont need to worry, it will close itself.